# Delphi static variable

Tags: delphi, static, delphi-5

In my class, i need to use a static variable ( `static int next_id`; in C++)

I use

```
private
    class var next_id: Integer;
```

I get Error : `PROCEDURE or FUNCTION expected`. How to declare some variable with **Delphi 5** ?

Comment: I think a simple local (in "implementation") var will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Rudy's answer...

Delphi 5 did not yet have this available. But you could at least declare a global variable. I won't copy Rudy's code, but I will add that in order to initialize them (and clean them up if necessary), you should use the `initialization` (and `finalization`) sections of a unit. These go on the very bottom of a Delphi unit, like so...

```
unit Whatever;

...

interface

...

implementation

...

initialization
  MyGlobalVar := TMyGlobalVar.Create;
finalization
  FreeAndNil(MyGlobalVar);
end.
```

Or in your case...

```
initialization
  next_ID := 1;
```

And your scenario in particular won't require a `finalization` section.

Answer (score 7):

In Delphi 5, you can't. No class vars in Delphi 5 yet.

The next best thing is a global variable in the implementation section of the unit, though.

```
unit Whatever;

...

implementation

var
  next_ID: Integer;

...

initialization
  next_ID := 0;

end.
```

Or alternatively, at the very bottom:

```
begin
  next_ID := 0;
end.
```

Comment: Thank you ..It's possible to use some global variable as static variable for all instance? and where i can initialize this global variable?

Comment: @user6751794 You should take a look at `initialization` and `finalization` sections at the bottom of units. That seems like the ideal thing in your case.

Comment: plus1. I think a simple local (implementation) var will do it.

Answer (score -1):

Sample of class variable declaration:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

type
  GlobalData = class
    class var V1: String;
    class var X1: Integer;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

usage sample from other unit:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GlobalData.V1 := 'Yahoo';
end;
```

you don't need to create and destroy this class. it will be created automatically before everything else.

what is wrong in your sample: class variable must be declared inside class. i don't see `class declaration` in your sample. plus, as was mentioned before, Delphi 5 (very very old) do not support this feature.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan -- have you ever read till end. did you saw `Delphi 5 (very very old) do not support this feature. answered 12 hours ago` ?

Comment: Not much use then is it. And the penultimate paragraph is a little misleading.